# Sonata Media Bundle

Tags: video, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I have a problem with sonata.media.provider.file. When I'm trying to upload video using sonata.media.provider.file, And try to create video thumbnail. It is not working.

This documentation Say's http://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/helpers.html

"The sonata.media.provider.file provider does not generate thumbnails."

Ok.

So, What can I do If I do not want to upload video through youtube provider, dailymotion provider or vimeo provider in media bundle.

I want to upload custom video and generate thumbnail. How It is possible in Sonata media bundle ?

I want to know this is bug or not given functionality by Sonata media bundle ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a bundle to do this.

[SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle](https://github.com/xmon/SonataMediaProviderVideoBundle)

Just follow install and config details.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not give functionality by Sonata Media Bundle. What I think is you must write your own provider called Video and override generateThumbnails where you should generate your thumbnails with ffmpeg and {% media media %} to write out JS containing code of your video player (JWPlayer or something else). Maybe they didn't did that cuz of many many different video players. :)

BTW. If you write provider please share here, I want that too. :))